# How to launch new activity that contains info about list item?

Tags: android, search, android-listview

I have created a search functionality and a list. On selecting single list item i would like to launch new activity that contains info about that list item. I searched for solutions but I haven't found anything useful for me as a complete beginner.

This is a Main Activity File:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // List view
    private ListView lv;

    // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;


    // ArrayList for Listview
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Listview Data
        String products[] = {"Dell Inspiron", "HTC One X", "HTC Wildfire S", "HTC Sense", "HTC Sensation XE",
                                "iPhone 4S", "Samsung Galaxy Note 800",
                                "Samsung Galaxy S3", "MacBook Air", "Mac Mini", "MacBook Pro"};

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

        // Adding items to listview
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        /**
         * Enabling Search Filter
         * */
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);  
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                         
            }
        });
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For launching a new activity, with additional informations, use extras. For example, this is how you would launch a new Activity:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this, MyActivityToLaunch.class);
intent.putExtras("KEY_FOR_THE_VALUE", "value that is added as extra");
startActivity(intent);
```

This way, when the new Activity is launched, you can retrieve the added extra. For example, this is how you would get it:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    /*initialize here, like you would normally*/

    Bundle extras=getIntent.getExtras(); //get the extras here
    String myValue;
    if(extras!=null) //just to be sure, check if the extras exist
    {
        myValue=extras.getStringExtra("KEY_FOR_THE_VALUE"); //notice that the key value is the same as when you putted in the extra
    }
    else myValue="Error: getExtras() returned null";
}
```

Pardon me, if there is any syntax error, since I am not near any IDE, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement the following

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
                       Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyActivityToLaunch.class);
                       String item = lv.getAdapter().getItem(arg2).toString();
                       intent.putExtras("KEY", item);
                        startActivity(intent);        
        }
    };
```

using the same key "KEY", you retrieve the item in the launched activity

This [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html) will help you learn more about intents :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a problem when we use position (arg2) together with Filter.

**Eg:**
**Problem is:**

- Before filtering,
  ArrayList-->[AA,BB,AC]
  List-->

  AA
  BB
  AC
- After filtering,
  ArrayList-->[AA,BB,AC]
  List-->

  AA
  AC

So, when using`arg2`(**position**), after filtering, if you click on 'AC', `arraylist.get(arg2)` will return 'BB'.

**Solution:**

Use `arg1`(**View**) instead. It is the current single row item View, which you have clicked.

Refer following code fragment:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                            long arg3) {
             TextView txt=(TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
             String product=txt.getText().toString();
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, product, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
             intent.putExtra("KEY", product);
             startActivity(intent); 

           }
    });
```